# Which is best method for native apps action both on ios and android IJavaScriptExecutor ot TouchAction class?

Tags: android, selenium, c#-4.0, automation, appium

hi i am developing the automation code for both my ios and android. I have to perform the swiping scrolling actions. Sometime IJavaScriptExecutor works sometimes its not.can anyone help me around here for the method should i choose that works for both ios and android.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TouchAction class and it works fine:

```
TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver).longPress(WebElement).moveTo(WebElement).release();
action.perform();
```